# Passing a file path to COPY ... TO PROGRAM

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to pass a file path to `lp` using `COPY ... TO PROGRAM 'lp';`.

If I store the file path in a table and query that with `SELECT` within `COPY` statement, it gets passed as a string (i.e `echo /path/to/file.pdf | lp`) and `lp` would print that string instead of printing the file itself which is a pdf file.

Is there a way to do this within PostgreSQL or a trick that would pass-to/take-from query the result and pass it to the shell command as file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL in a `DO` statement using [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'COPY ... TO PROGRAM %L',
              (SELECT format('echo %L | lp', path) FROM configuration)
           );
END;$$;
```

In this example `configuration` is a one row table with a column `path` that holds the path name – adapt the query as needed.

The placeholder `%L` is replaced with the second argument, properly escaped as string literal. That way, you avoid the danger of SQL injection.

Comment: SUPER! Thanks. But I made a minor change that I ask you please to make in the answer for others to benefit. The pipe I put was just an example of how the `COPY ... TO PROGRAM` hands over the result of `SELECT` to `lp`. The way I figured it would be done is to use the same solution you've but use `lp %L` instead of `echo %L | lp`. Thanks again!

Comment: Assuming I want to do that in a trigger function on a table with many rows, could you please point out how to deal with `path` and `configuration` parameters?

Comment: You don't do that in a trigger. Never do something inside a database transaction that could take unpredictably long.